# Spring controller that will accept (XML/BASE64) and return XML with jackson support

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm creating a spring based web application(Spring,jackson and hibernate) that will accept XML/BASE64 input as request message and after processing the response will be XML message. Application will have different controllers to accept BASE64/XML message.

Client ---(BASE64/XML)-->Server---->XML--->Client

I need to know how to implement two different controller and can read the XML from the client. Since it is a web application, which will get input message based on client request. Request XML messages contains optional tags which may/may not be present. I need to know is it good to create the application as a spring web service(Please guide me with proper sample links) or like a normal web application that will read data from the input stream.

My client programs which will open a url connection, open stream writes the data and will wait for the server to write response back to stream.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

   //Function to take request and response as XML
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allEmployyes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody EmployeesStatus readAllEmployeeDetails() {
    }

   //Function to take request as BASE64 and reply as XML
    @RequestMapping(value = "/empProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ProfileStatus updateEmployeeProfilePic() {
    }
 }
```

Please help me to create a better solution for the requirement(Expecting practical solutions from experienced Spring professionals).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using [`@RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) that meets your requirements.  Note: I'm using [`Project Lombok`](https://projectlombok.org) annotation processing to reduce boilerplate getters and setters, but you're by no means obligated to use it.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class EmployeeController {
    /**
     * Reads employee details and returns status.
     *
     * @param employeeDetails the employee details
     * @return a status object
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allEmployees", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public EmployeeStatus readAllEmployeeDetails(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDetails employeeDetails) {
        log.info("Got employee details: {}", employeeDetails);
        return new EmployeeStatus("Employee details updated");
    }

    /**
     * Reads a Base64 encoded picture and returns status.
     *
     * @param picture the Base64 encoded picture
     * @return a status object
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/empProfile", method = POST, consumes = TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ProfileStatus updateEmployeeProfilePic(
            @Valid
            // Regular expression for validating Base64 encoded text.
            @Pattern(message = "Not Base64 encoded", regexp = "^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$")
            @RequestBody String picture) {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(picture);
        log.info("Received {} bytes", bytes.length);
        // Process bytes...
        return new ProfileStatus("Picture updated");
    }

    /**
     * Handles validation constraint violations by returning a 400 Bad Request, and outputs the violation messages.
     *
     * @param e        the {@link ConstraintViolationException}
     * @param response the {@link HttpServletResponse}
     * @throws IOException on unexpected I/O error
     */
    @ExceptionHandler
    public void handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String message = e.getConstraintViolations().stream()
                .map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        response.sendError(BAD_REQUEST.value(), message);
    }

    @Data
    public static class EmployeeDetails {
        @NotEmpty
        private String firstName;
        @NotEmpty
        private String lastName;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class EmployeeStatus {
        private String status;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class ProfileStatus {
        private String status;
    }
}
```

Here is the Maven POM I'm using for the controller.  The key is to include [`jackson-dataformat-xml`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) as a dependency for XML serialization support:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.anoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>stack-44893803-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This allows you to POST XML, and to serialize/deserialize it using Jackson:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/employee/allEmployees \
  -H 'content-type: application/xml' \
  -d '<employee>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
</employee>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to solve this can use the method like below
```

```

and change the controller to
```

```
//Function to take request and response as XML
@RequestMapping(value = "/allEmployyes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void EmployeesStatus readAllEmployeeDetails(HttpServletResponse response) {
      ...
  ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
  String xmlStr =  xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(someresult);
  try {
         response.getWriter().write(xmlStr);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         log.error("Io Exception!",e);
      }
}
```

```